# Mule default thread settings

Tags: java, performance, mule

I'm using Mule 3.3.1.  I've found articles discussing configuration of thread usage (maxThreadsActive, etc.).  However, most of them say something like "the default settings are probably good enough" but don't mention what those are.

Is the default behavior that threads growth is unlimited?  If not, is there a site that I simply haven't stumbled on that lists all the default settings for tuning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.mule.api.config.ThreadingProfile.DEFAULT_DO_THREADING):

```
public static final boolean     DEFAULT_DO_THREADING    true
public static final int     DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE     0
public static final long    DEFAULT_MAX_THREAD_TTL  60000L
public static final int     DEFAULT_MAX_THREADS_ACTIVE  16
public static final int     DEFAULT_MAX_THREADS_IDLE    1
public static final int     DEFAULT_POOL_EXHAUST_ACTION     4
public static final long    DEFAULT_THREAD_WAIT_TIMEOUT     30000L
public static final int     WHEN_EXHAUSTED_ABORT    3
public static final int     WHEN_EXHAUSTED_DISCARD  1
public static final int     WHEN_EXHAUSTED_DISCARD_OLDEST   2
public static final int     WHEN_EXHAUSTED_RUN  4
public static final int     WHEN_EXHAUSTED_WAIT     0
```